# After dist-upgrade form 12.04 to 14.04 imagick not loaded

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04, apache2, upgrade, imagemagick

After my *dist-upgrade* of Ubuntu Server form 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS, the module *ImageMagick* won't load anymore.

I get every 30 minutes an alter email with the following :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/imagick.so' - liblcms2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Is it consecutive to the upgrade, or fortuity !?

**EDIT:**

So, Imagemagick name has changed, now it's imagick ! Simply remove and reinstall it under its new name :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "imagemagick"
sudo apt-get --purge remove "php5-imagick*"

sudo apt-get install imagemagick && php5-imagick
sudo php5enmod imagick

sudo service apache2 restart
```

But I still receive email alert saying :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/gmagick.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/gmagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/gmagick.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/gmagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

When I search on my sytem in /etc/ any conf file trying to access this file, nothing is returned (excepted /etc/pear/pear.conf). Here is the find syntax :

```
egrep -lir  "20121212" .
```

What can I do to stop having this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the uninstall of ImageMagick doesn't remove (apparently) the `extension=imagick.so` in php.ini.

I needed to remove it manually. I don't know why, but it was referenced 2 times in the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file.